# What does the second parameter do in Doctrine query builder calls?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am new to Doctrine query builder and I am trying to understand to use it along with Symfony:

```
$queryBuilder
->select('u.id', 'u.name')
->from('users', 'u')
->where('u.email = ?')
;
```

In this scenario, what does the 'u' stand for?

Comment: Documentations are just made for this.

Comment: @gp_sflover I am sure that at one point you ask for clarification even after reading documentation.

Comment: Chris: you're right that beginners often need clarification. However, I wonder if @gp_sflover is correct too: readers here warmly encourage the reading of documentation, and prior research in general. A good way to ask questions of this type is to say "I found from the documentation that the second parameter is a table alias, but I am not sure what the purpose of this is, and whether it is mandatory". That will show readers that you've made a solid effort first, and sometimes you'll get upvotes for doing so, as well as more readers willing to give expansive answers.

Comment: @halfer yea, I understand, thanks for pushing me guys.  One thing i love about stackoverflow.  But i did read the docs, I am just having a hard time understanding Doctrine and building with querybuilder, my lead ask me to build a symfony command that runs a sql query and then add it as a cronjob.  I know sql and php but having a hard time wrapping my head around Doctrine.

Comment: @halfer pointed out exactly my point of view, in fact my comment was strictly related to the " what does the 'u' stand for?" part, because this is clearly described in the docs :-). I'll be happy to help you Chris for your next (better formed) question :-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `u` is a so called identification variable or alias that refers to the `MyProject\Model\User` class. By placing this alias in the `SELECT` clause we specify that we want all instances of the `User` class that are matched by this query to appear in the query result

Doctrine has excellent documentation, you can refer to it [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Comment: so in theory, we could omit the 'u'?

Comment: Yes, in a simple query like this you can, identification is mostly used when you get into joins.

Comment: I have a feeling that DQL requires aliases but I am not sure. As for the query builder, I think aliases were mandatory but I think this was changed in 2.5.

Comment: @Chris You could omit 'u' from a small and simple query like this, but I suggest you get into the habit of using aliases. When Queries become more complicated, you will be grateful. .

Answer (score 1):

'u' refers to the 'users' table. In other words, 'u' is an alias.

so 'u.email' is the column named 'email' from the 'users' table.